# installing the OS twice on same hard disk drive

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, bootloader

I plan to install Ubuntu 13.10 twice on the same HDD. The reason is each installed OS will have filesystem tweaks different from the other.

Below is my plan:

- First primary (bootable) partition will hold grub bootloader of the
  first installed OS.
- Second primary (bootable) partition will hold grub bootloader of the
  second installed OS
- First logical (non-bootable) partition will hold the first installed
  OS.
- Second logical (non-bootable) partition will hold the second installed OS

Will my computer become confused if I install two grub bootloaders of the same OS on to the same partition? That is why I install each grub bootloader in a separate partition, is that right?

Comment: Filesystem "tweaks"? You can do what you want to on your computer, but your reasoning seems [specious](http://funroll-loops.info/) to me.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch: The reason for doing so is to be found in the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/434655/how-do-i-add-a-new-user-with-specific-configuration-files/434685?noredirect=1#comment565636_434685

Comment: I answered your question there. Use a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

Answer (score 2):

Why not share grub (in the MBR) and swap? This can be accomplished fairly easily by installing, leaving some space... and then installing again into that free space.

There's no reason to keep two copies of grub clattering around.

Comment: I am new to Linux. Please show me how to share grub (in the MBR), swap, leaving some space....